# Best way to download data from SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, windows-8.1, csom

So, I am developing an Windows 8.1 Application wich communicates with SharePoint 2013.

Currently I'm using the following way to download the data:

```
    public async Task<IList<NewsSite>> GetGroups(string vaultResource)
    {
        _clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, PassWord);

        SP.Web site = _clientContext.Web;
        ListCollection announcementListCollection = site.Lists;
        _clientContext.Load(announcementListCollection);

        List<NewsItem> NewsItems = new List<NewsItem>();

        //load all news items wich are announcement items for all lists in the current site.

        _clientContext.Load(announcementListCollection);
        _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



        foreach (List sharePointGroup in announcementListCollection)
        {
            var ctypes = sharePointGroup.ContentTypes;
            _clientContext.Load(ctypes);
            _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            if (ctypes.Where(c => c.Name == "Announcement").Count() == 1)
            {
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>8</RowLimit></View>";

                ListItemCollection newsListColl = sharePointGroup.GetItems(camlQuery);

                _clientContext.Load(newsListColl,
                    eachItem => eachItem.Include(item => item.Id, item => item["Title"], item => item["Body"]));
                _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (ListItem NewsItem in newsListColl)
                {
                    NewsItem newsItem = new NewsItem();
                    newsItem.Id = NewsItem.Id;
                    newsItem.Title = (string) NewsItem["Title"];
                    newsItem.Content = (string) NewsItem["Body"];
                    newsItem.ListHolder = sharePointGroup.Title;

                    string tempImageString = GetImageInHTML((string) NewsItem["Body"]);
                    var rgx1 = new Regex("http");
                    if (tempImageString != null)
                    {
                        var match = rgx1.Match(tempImageString);
                        if (match.Success)
                        {
                            newsItem.Image = Regex.Replace(tempImageString, "&#58;", ":");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string pattern2 = @"http(s)?://(www\.)?\w*((.\w*)|(-*\w*))?(\.\w*)?";
                            var rgx2 = new Regex(pattern2);
                            string imgUrl = rgx2.Match(_siteUrl).ToString() + tempImageString;


                            newsItem.Image = imgUrl;
                        }
                    }
                    if (tempImageString == null)
                    {
                        newsItem.Image = null;
                    }
                    NewsItems.Add(newsItem);
                }
            }
        }
        var newsItemsBySite =
                NewsItems.GroupBy(x => x.ListHolder).Select(x => new NewsSite {Title = x.Key, Items = x.ToList()});

        return newsItemsBySite.ToList();

    }
```

Via this way, the App makes 3 calls to the SharePoint site for each ListItem to get the data it need.

I tried to put all the load statements in one statement, but without succes.

Does anybody know how to put the 3 statements in one statement or a better and faster way to retrieve the Data?

For the Reccord: I'm using the SharePoint CLIENT Object Model.

Looking forward to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your basic approach to getting data here.

Given that you're looking to gather data from across an indeterminate number of lists, in you're after all Announcements which could be in any lists you should look to use another data access API, Search. Seriously, Search is going to be so much faster for you.

To get all the announcements in a site your query is going to be nice and simple you'll just have to make a request to `http://SiteUrl/_api/search/query?querytext=%27ContentTypeId:0x01*%27`
Just hit that in your web browser and see the shape of your results.

[Tobias Zimmergren](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-searching-in-sharepoint-2013-using-the-rest-new-apis) and [Chris O'Brien](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/calling-sharepoint-search-using-rest-eg.html) have great blog posts on sing the REST Search API. This approach does have the limitation that the results are only as fresh as the last search crawl, but it's so much faster and more efficient

Comment: I know search is way faster than my current approach. But, as I forgot to mention, my task is to create an application which doesn't need any customization to SharePoint to work, and since Search is not default configured, I am not allowed to use this method. Still your answer is helpful! I'll keep it in mind for some other time! Tnx!